# Read quaternions like complex numbers in Racket

Tags: racket, quaternions

Racket has the ability to read complex numbers in a format such as 2+3i, such that 
    (+ 2+3i 4) 
is valid, and will return 6+3i. My goal is to allow the user to create a quaternion in the same manner, such that 
    (+ 1+2i+3j+4k 3+4i+2j+1k) 
does not throw any "undefined identifier" errors. Quaternions are what I'm specifically trying to implement, but this is a more general question of how to change how the Racket reader parses numbers. Section 1.3.3 of [this page](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html) outlines the number grammar in BNF, and this is what I want to change (specifically, exact/inexact complex). What is the best way to allow the reader to recognize quaternions written in such a format?

Comment: This question may be related: [Create Suffixed Numbers in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544083/create-suffixed-numbers-racket/53544456). It is not a duplicate, but the same two general categories of solutions apply: (1) redefine what "undefined" identifiers mean with `#%top`, or (2) make a reader extension that turns them into "quaternions values" instead of identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The Little Schemer and The Seductive Computer are useful reads. My personal opinion would be to overload the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that would probably get a better answer on the racket mailing list, http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/ . You can define your own reader, but the question is how extensible the existing reader framework is, and whether it's possible to add to the BNF in a modular way. My guess is that you're going to wind up duplicating quite a bit of code, but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's been a while, but I had the same question...

I solved it (partially) using only syntax-case, a struct representing the quaternion, regex and some syntax overriding for the operators.

When the default reader finds something like `1i+2j+3k` it reads as an identifier, which you can manipulate at expansion time by splicing syntax or converting to a symbol or string with `syntax-e` and `symbol->string`.

For it to be recognized as a struct, you have to override the `#%top` syntax to expand or call a function that expands the identifier as a struct syntax.

This is the ugly part, since it requires some heavy syntax manipulation and expanding to do it right, or some weird regex to do it wrong, but functioning. Although not recommended, some simple regex can get you what you need, since it's doubtful you'll ever need to write down a quaternion with float parts as a literal and most likely you'll only need it for simple representations like a direction quaternion with real part 0 such as `1j`

Comment: This question may be related: [Create Suffixed Numbers in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544083/create-suffixed-numbers-racket/53544456). It is not a duplicate, but the same two general categories of solutions apply: (1) redefine what "undefined" identifiers mean with `#%top`, or (2) make a reader extension that turns them into "quaternions values" instead of identifiers. And the code in my answer to that question might be useful if you want to do this yourself