# Create suffixed numbers Racket

Tags: numbers, racket

I'm trying to experiment with what I can do in Racket, and I want to suffix numbers with letters.

For this example, I'd simply like to represent `10000` as `10K`, and `1000000` as `1M`.

Is there way (with macros or otherwise) that I can expand `1M` to:

```
(* 1 1000000)
```

Or something to that effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Racket, things like `10K` are *identifiers*, which normally would refer to variables. There are two ways to make them into numbers:

#### 1: redefine what "undefined" identifiers mean

You can redefine what to do on an undefined identifier by defining a `#%top` macro.

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define
         (only-in racket [#%top old-#%top]))

(define-syntax-parser #%top
  [(_ . x:id)
   #:when (id-has-a-k-at-the-end? #'x)
   (transform-id-into-number #'x)]
  [(_ . x)
   #'(old-#%top . x)])
```

However, this has a subtle problem. If there are any identifiers or variables in your program with K's on the end, they could override any numbers that were written that way. You would need to be careful not to accidentally override something that was intended to be a number.

#### 2: make a reader extension that turns them into numbers instead of identifiers

This will take more time, but it's closer to the "right way" to do this, since it avoids conflicts when variables happen to have K's on the end.

One of the easier ways to extend the reader is with a [*readtable*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/readtables.html?q=read-syntax%2Frecu). You can make a function that extends a readtable like this:

```
;; Readtable -> Readtable
(define (extend-readtable orig-rt)
  ;; Char InputPort Any Nat Nat Nat -> Any
  (define (rt-proc char in src ln col pos)
    ....)
  ...
  (make-readtable orig-rt
    #f 'non-terminating-macro rt-proc
    ...))
```

To use this to define a `#lang` language, you need to put the reader implementation in `your-language/lang/reader.rkt`. Here that's `number-with-k/lang/reader.rkt`, where the `number-with-k` directory is installed as a single-collection package (`raco pkg install path/to/number-with-k`).

**number-with-k/lang/reader.rkt**

```
#lang racket

(provide (rename-out [-read read]
                     [-read-syntax read-syntax]
                     [-get-info get-info]))

(require syntax/readerr
         syntax/module-reader)

;; Readtable -> Readtable
(define (extend-readtable orig-rt)
  ;; Char InputPort Any Nat Nat Nat -> Any
  (define (rt-proc char in src ln col pos)
    ....)
  ...
  (make-readtable orig-rt
    #f 'non-terminating-macro rt-proc))

;; [X ... -> Y] -> [X ... -> Y]
(define ((wrap-reader rd) . args)
  (parameterize ([current-readtable (extend-readtable (current-readtable))])
    (apply rd args)))

(define-values [-read -read-syntax -get-info]
  (make-meta-reader 'number-with-k
                    "language path"
                    lang-reader-module-paths
                    wrap-reader
                    wrap-reader
                    identity))
```

The main work goes into filling in the `....` holes in the `extend-readtable` function. For example, you can make it recognize identifiers that end with `K` like this:

```
;; Readtable -> Readtable
(define (extend-readtable orig-rt)
  ;; Char InputPort Any Nat Nat Nat -> Any
  (define (rt-proc char in src ln col pos)
    (define v (read-syntax/recursive src in char orig-rt #f))
    (cond
      [(and (identifier? v) (id-has-a-k-at-the-end? v))
       (transform-id-into-number v)]
      [else
       v]))

  (make-readtable orig-rt
    #f 'non-terminating-macro rt-proc))
```

Once this is done, and you have the `number-with-k` directory installed as a package, you should be able to use `#lang number-with-k` like this:

```
#lang number-with-k racket

(+ 12K 15)
; => 12015
```

Comment: I thought of `#%top` as well, and you could use `identifier-binding` to check whether the identifier already has a binding - if it does, you probably want to skip the transformation.

Comment: An `identifier-binding` check would not be enough to avoid the problems, because if the identifier is defined, it won't invoke `#%top` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest to is to define the suffixes you need.

```
(define K 1000)
(define M 1000000)
```

Then write `(* 3.14 M)` for 3.14 millions.

As others mention, Racket supports scientific notation  `3.14E6` is also 3.14 million.

Yet another alternative is to define functions `K`, `M` etc like:

```
(define (M x) (* x 1000000))
```

Then you can write

```
(M 3.14)
```

to mean 3.14 million.

Answer (score 1):

Racket does already have [built in support for this, kind of](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/numbers.html), via scientific notation:

```
1e6 ; 1000000.0 ("1M")
2e7 ; 20000000.0
```